# Internal Server Error when Deleting Event from Group Calendar

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am primarily using the .net Microsoft graph client.  I can create and change a  group calendar's events with the API, but cannot delete them.

I know that my GraphServiceClient has a good user context token.

My code is

```
await client.Groups[GroupId.ToString()].Events[DeadlineId].Request().DeleteAsync();
```

I have also tried using an HTTP client "Delete" event to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{GroupId}/events/{EventId}`

The response I get is:

```
Error Received:
     {
     "error": {
     "code": "ErrorInternalServerError",
     "message": "[0x30140102] BodyTag",
     "innerError": {
     "request-id": "2ab3ad41-b6e2-47d1-88cc-ef3a3640d153",
     "date": "2017-06-29T04:08:38"
     }
     }
 }
```

Am I doing something wrong or is there a problem on Microsoft's end?

Comment: Have you tried using `Calendar` instead of `Events`? `/groups/{id}/calendar/events/{id}/`